# I am trying to get my double linked list to display numbers 0 -> 10;

Tags: c, data-structures, append, doubly-linked-list, function-definition

This is the struct definition.

```
typedef struct doubleLinkedList
{
  struct doubleLinkedList *prevPtr;
  int data;
  struct doubleLinkedList *nextPtr;
} dNode;

typedef dNode *dNodePtr;
```

These are the functions performed on the struct

This is a function to create the double linked Node

```
dNodePtr create(int val) {
    //Instantiate a new dNodePtr
    dNodePtr newNode = (dNodePtr) malloc(sizeof(dNode));
    newNode->data = val;
    newNode->prevPtr = NULL;
    newNode->nextPtr = NULL;
    return newNode;
}
```

this is a function to append the double liked node

```
void append(dNodePtr* head, int val) {
    //Check if the list's empty
    if(!(*head)){
        printf("Empty list:  can't append...creating instead\n");
        *head = create(val);
    }
    //Create a new Node to hold the value
    dNodePtr valNode = (dNodePtr) malloc(sizeof(dNode));  //New Node
    valNode->data = val;        //Store value
    valNode->nextPtr = NULL;    //Terminate
    dNodePtr aNode = *head;     //Reference to head node
    while(aNode->nextPtr){
        aNode = aNode->nextPtr;
    }
    // Insert at end of list
    valNode->prevPtr = aNode;   
    aNode->nextPtr = valNode;  
}
```

This is a function to display the node via terminal.

```
void display(dNodePtr* head) {
  dNodePtr aNode = *head;
  printf("Printing\n");
  while(!aNode){
    printf("%d\n", aNode->data);
    aNode = aNode->nextPtr;
  }
  printf("Done\n");
}
```

Comment: You forgot to tell us what the problem is.

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is a place for asking **specific** programming questions. You may want to read this for further information: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/12149471)

Comment: `while(!aNode)` -> `while (aNode)`.

Comment: <O/T> your `append` function creates 2 nodes if the list is empty. You should either do `if(...) { ... create(); return;}` or `if(...) { create(); }else{ /*create new node*/ }`

Comment: also from a design perspective, it would be better IMO if you called `create` any time you want to create a node. Currently you have the `create` function plus create functionality in `append`. Your functions should do one thing and do it well.

Answer (score 0):

The function `displa`y is incorrect. The condition in the while statement will evaluate to logical true only when the pointer `aNode` is equal to `NULL`.

```
while(!aNode){
```

Instead you have to write

```
while( aNode ){
```

The function `append` is also incorrect. When initially the list is empty that is the pointer to the head node is equal to `NULL` the function creates two nodes with the same value

```
if(!(*head)){
    printf("Empty list:  can't append...creating instead\n");
    *head = create(val);
}
//Create a new Node to hold the value
dNodePtr valNode = (dNodePtr) malloc(sizeof(dNode));  //New Node
//...
```

Also outputting a message in this case does not make a sense.

The function can be defined at least like

```
void append(dNodePtr* head, int val) {
    //Check if the list's empty
    if( *head == NULL ){
        *head = create(val);
    }
    else
    {
        dNodePtr aNode = *head;     //Reference to head node
        while(aNode->nextPtr){
            aNode = aNode->nextPtr;
        }
        // Insert at end of list
        aNode->nextPtr = create(val);
        aNode->nextPtr->prevPtr = aNode;
    }   
}
```